# How to get rows with similar values in two different columns using command line?

Tags: bash

I have following example data from a large file.

```
cont100 1128 1125
cont1005 3642 3642
cont1006 103 19
cont1037 3146 3146
cont104 895 890
cont1056 934 934
cont1059 1750 1750
cont1072 2577 2577
cont1078 43 42
cont1081 727 2
```

I need to get only the rows with similar values in column 2 and column 3. The output should be like this.

```
cont1005 3642 3642
cont1037 3146 3146
cont1056 934 934
cont1059 1750 1750
cont1072 2577 2577
```

Also I need to get the inverse of that. That means I need to get the rows with values that are not similar in the columns. The output should be like this.

```
cont100 1128 1125
cont1006 103 19
cont104 895 890
cont1078 43 42
cont1081 727 2
```

Comment: Do you mean **identical** values in columns 2 and 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is easy to do with awk, e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092693/awk-concise-way-to-check-if-2-fields-match-the-same-string).

For your example, with your data in `file`:

```
%  awk '$2 != $3 {print $0}' file
# outputs
cont100 1128 1125
cont1006 103 19
cont104 895 890
cont1078 43 42
cont1081 727 2

%  awk '$2 == $3 {print $0}' file
# outputs:
cont1005 3642 3642
cont1037 3146 3146
cont1056 934 934
cont1059 1750 1750
cont1072 2577 2577
```

Note that where you say "similar" I am interpreting that to mean "exactly the same", because that is the case in your example.

Comment: It worked and I got the result that I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The Perl solution is similar to the awk solution from *MaximilianPress*:

Print lines with identical values in columns 2 and 3:

```
perl -lane 'print if $F[1] == $F[2];' in.txt

# Prints:
cont1005 3642 3642
cont1037 3146 3146
cont1056 934 934
cont1059 1750 1750
cont1072 2577 2577
```

Print lines with different values in columns 2 and 3:

```
perl -lane 'print if $F[1] != $F[2];' in.txt

# Prints:
cont100 1128 1125
cont1006 103 19
cont104 895 890
cont1078 43 42
cont1081 727 2
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option. Arrays in Perl are 0-indexed.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)